# JAVA_HOME not set properly

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to configure hadoop in cygwin.
I have set `JAVA_HOME` as `/cygdrive/c/work/java/jdk1.6.0_30`
If I echo `$JAVA_HOME`, it displays correctly.

If I run the command  `bin/hadoop version` it is giving the following error message:

`/bin/java :No such file or directory.`

Comment: You may want to take a look at the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30143230/1291727

Answer (score 1):

The error message has nothing to do with `JAVA_HOME`. You have to add the path where your java is to the `PATH` variable:

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/java
export $PATH
```